# Filter all products by region, Ransack and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ransac

I have set up Ajax search and sorting using Ransack.I am able to search from text field, sort by product name, price etc.

Now I want to add functionality to click on location link. Like Latvia, Poland and then dynamically display only products from that location.

My code:

**Associations**

*Product.rb*

```
belongs_to :region
```

*Region.rb*

```
has_many :products
```

My search form:

```
    <%= search_form_for @search, :class=>"search",:remote=>"true", url: products_path, :method => :get do |f| %>


    <%= sort_link @search, :height,"AUGUMS", {}, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %>

    <%= sort_link @search, :price,"CENA", {}, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %>



     <% slice.each do |region| -%>
         <li>  
           <%= sort_link @search,'region.products',region.name, {}, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %>

        </li>
    <% end -%>      
    <%end%>
```

**My controller**:

```
  @adver = Product.all
  @search = @adver.search(search_params)
  @search.sorts = 'name' if @search.sorts.empty?
  @advertisements = @search.result().page(params[:page])
```

**Problem:**

When I click such region link.It just change order to ASC or DESC for all products on page.

What I expect is, click on region link retrieve just those products that are in that region.

What I am doing wrong ?

Any help would be great.
Thanks.